# How do I test an effect that returns multiple actions

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an effect that returns action A then action B

```
@Effect() myEffect$: Observable <Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType('MY_ACTION')
  .switchMap(() => Observable.of(
    // subscribers will be notified
    { type: 'ACTION_ONE' },
    // subscribers will be notified (again ...)
    { type: 'ACTION_TWO' }
  ));
```

How can I test the two successive returned actions ?

```
it('should return action one then action two', () => {
  runner.queue(new myAction());
  const expectedResult = twoSuccesiveActions;
  sessionEffect.myEffect$.subscribe(result => {
    // how do I test those two succesively returned actions
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use one with `take(1)` and one with `skip(1)`:

```
it('should return action one then action two', () => {
  const expectedResult = twoSuccesiveActions;
  sessionEffect.myEffect$.take(1).subscribe(result => {
    // first action
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
  });

  sessionEffect.myEffect$.skip(1).take(1).subscribe(result => {
    // second action
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
  });

  runner.queue(new myAction());
});
```

In any case I would suggest you to use `take(1)` if you don't manually unsubscribe to ensure no leaks into other tests ect...

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is still wondering how to do it, this is another way to do it

```
effects.myEffect$
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(2)
  )
  .subscribe((emittedActions) => {
    /* You could also include here callings to services
        verify(myServiceMock.execute(anything()))
          .called();
    */
    expect(emittedActions.map((action) => action.type))
      .toEqual([
        myFirstAction,
        mySecondAction,
      ]);
    done();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

use pairwise like that:

```
it('should return a ACTION_ONE && ACTION_TWO',
  inject([EffectService, EffectsRunner], (service: EffectService, runner: EffectsRunner) => {
    runner.queue({type: USER_SWITCH_ROLE});

    service.myEffect$
      .pairwise()
      .subscribe(([result1, result2]) => {
        expect(result1).toEqual({type: ACTION_ONE, payload: {}});
        expect(result2).toEqual({type: ACTION_TWO, payload: {}});
      });
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered the [`toArray`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/toarray) operator:

> "Collects all source emissions and emits them as an array when the
> source completes."

```
sessionEffect.myEffect$
  .pipe(toArray())
  .subscribe(result =>
    expect(result).toHaveLength(2);
    expect(result[0]).toBeInstanceOf(ExpectedAction1);
    expect(result[1]).toBeInstanceOf(ExpectedAction2);
  });
```